# Different free storage space reported in the Files app and in Settings → iPad Storage

Tags: ipad, storage, settings, ios

The reported value looks off by ~38 GB

1. Settings → General → iPad Storage:

   [image: 20,68 GB of 64 GB Used]
2. Files → On My iPad:

   [image: 5,47 GB available]

I'm trying to Airdrop a 9 GB file to this iPad and it fails, this could be why. Smaller files (~1,5 GB) get transferred just fine.

Rebooted the device several times. Is this fixable without a reset of any kind?

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3316346 no answer yet about file size limit of airdrop.

Comment: *confirmed*: after i reset this ipad and files finally showed more free space, airdrop started working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution (kind of): delete the files app, and then install it from the app store. That made it report different storage usage, that was more in line with what's under settings → general, which is close to what I needed.

Of course it's a workaround, and make sure you back up your important stuff before proceeding.

Comment: just did this again; helped.

Comment: This didn't helped me. I still see 5,48 GB available in the On My iPhone. I have 57 GB free reported in Storage.